# Matlab - FEM: Meshing polygon

Tags: matlab, polygon, mesh, finite-element-analysis

I have problem with meshing this polygon:

[image]

I need fill this polygon with one of this finite element:

[image]

I don't how to type a code for this problem and then plot this polygon with mesh, all without using PDEtool.

Thank you.

Comment: Delaunay-Triangulation!

Comment: What kind of FEM solver are you using? Does it do automatic mesh refinement?

Comment: Everything in Matlab

Comment: Well that doesn't answer my questions at all.

Comment: Have a look at the [triangulation class](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/triangulation-class.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made sth like that:

```
matX = [0,0.2,0;
        0.2,0.2,0;
        0.2,1,0.2;
        1,1,0.2;
        0,0.2,0;
        0.2,0.2,0;
        0.2,1,0.2]

matY = [0,0,0.5;
        0,0.5,0.5;
        0,0,0.5;
        0,0.5,0.5;
        0.5,0.5,1;
        0.5,1,1;
        0.5,0.5,1]

x = zeros(7,4);
y = zeros(7,4);    

for i=1:7    
    x(i,:) = [matX(i,1),matX(i,2),matX(i,3),matX(i,1)];
    y(i,:) = [matY(i,1),matY(i,2),matY(i,3),matY(i,1)];
    plot(x(i,:),y(i,:))
    hold on
end
```

Mesh:

[image]

Have anyone better and more sophisticated solution?

Comment: Looks like a start to me.  Now you should do what every FEA practitioner would do: get a solution, refine the mesh, and continue until the answers don't change anymore.  It's called "checking convergence".

Comment: I made it all FEM stuff in Matlab. Our HW was like: create a program in Matlab, that will be calculate stress, strain etc similiar to NX, Catia etc. Really terrible HW, but done it, thank you for all your response, help me :)

Comment: Terrible HW?  Sounds like a great problem.

Comment: Not the best in examination period, a lot of exams. ;) But it is useful HW.